# How to make a filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, filter, django-filter

I want to do a filtering in django and I want to do this with date_created from custumUser for my filter. I can show date_create using list_display to my admin panel, but I can't filter through it on the page.
**my models.py like that**.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name='Email')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Username')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Last Name')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # this methods are require to login super user from admin panel
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # this methods are require to login super user from admin panel
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('user')
        verbose_name_plural = ('users')


class EmailConfirmed(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_confirmed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Email Confirmed'


@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_user_email_confirmation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        dt = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        email_confirmed_instance = EmailConfirmed(user=instance)
        user_encoded = f'{instance.email}-{dt}'.encode()
        activation_key = hashlib.sha224(user_encoded).hexdigest()
        email_confirmed_instance.activation_key = activation_key
        email_confirmed_instance.save()
```

**and my admin.py**

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_staff','is_superuser','date_created')
    list_filter = ('is_admin', 'is_staff','date_created',)
    field_sets = (
        (
            None, {'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')}
         ),
        (
            'Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}
        )
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None, {
                'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_superuser')})
    )
    ordering = ('email',)
    search_fields = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)


class EmailConfirmedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_created', 'email_confirmed', 'date_confirmed')
    list_filter = ('email_confirmed',  'date_confirmed', )

    def date_created(self, obj):
        return obj.user.date_created

    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name

    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name


admin.site.register(EmailConfirmed, EmailConfirmedAdmin)
```

and I want to add admin panel for use date_created filtering which is belong to CustomUser
when I write date_created in the list_filter I get error.
How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new object to know when it was created. Django by default give every model this field.

Try this in admin.py:

```
list_filter = ['created_at']
```